# How to add rows to a new custom table based on values in other table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to add duplicate entries in a new custom table from the inputs given in another table.

e.g. consider a table with columns

- Subscriber
- Effective_date
- Expiriation_date
- Service_Code

[image]

Now i want to dynamically create a custom table which will have duplicate entries with the same

- Subscriber
- Effective_date
- Expiriation_date
- Service_Code

I also need new columns for the dates between "Effective_date" & "Expiriation_date", so I could filter and see how many months a customer was subscribed for until leaving.

Right now I have this:

[image: the report problem image]

but instead of 3 - which is the number of month until the customer left, I want to see the months between:

May
June
July

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, this should give you what you want.

First, you will need a table full of dates. If you don't already have one, you can have PowerBI create one for you by clicking on 'Modeling' -> 'New Table' and then entering in this formula (you can alter the dates to expand or shrink the dates included in the table).

```
Dates = CALENDAR(DATE(2016, 1, 1), DATE(2017, 12, 31))
```

Then create a new table with this formula. This will give you a new table with rows for each date between the 'Effective_Date' and 'Expiration_Date' from the original table.

```
ServicePeriodExpanded = FILTER(CROSSJOIN(ServicePeriod, 'Dates'), ServicePeriod[Effective_Date] <= 'Dates'[Date] && IF(ServicePeriod[Expiration_Date] = BLANK(), TODAY(), ServicePeriod[Expiration_Date]) >= 'Dates'[Date])
```

Here are the results.

[image: Results]